# How to populate individual Incerement and Decrement buttons for each element?

Tags: reactjs, button, increment

[image]

Hello I am trying to develop simple shopping cart demo.I am iterating through a json file using map function in react.Json datas are displayed ok but increment button on click changes all values for all products how can I populate individual increment buttons and div for amount for each element?

Note:Late I want to display the total amount on top right as Total Price?

header.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class header extends Component {
    state = {
        totalcount: 2
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="./logo.png" id="logo" alt="" />
                    </a>
                    <button
                        className="navbar-toggler"
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
                        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    >
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item active">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                    Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                    Features
                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                    Pricing
                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>


                    </div>
                    <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"></input>
                    <button className="btn btn-success m-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                    <h2><span className={this.getClass()}>
                        Total Price: {this.formatCount()}
                    </span></h2>

                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
    getClass() {
        let classes = "badge";
        classes += this.state.count === 0 ? " badge-danger" : " badge-warning";
        return classes;
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { totalcount } = this.state;
        return totalcount === 0 ? "0 %n  Your Cart is Empty" : totalcount;
    }
}

export default header;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./components/main.js";
import Footer from "./components/footer.js";
import Header from "./components/header.js";
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';


ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById("header"));
ReactDOM.render(<Footer />, document.getElementById("footer"));
```

main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ProductInfo from '../plist.json'


class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  handleIncerement() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  }

  handleDecrement() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count - 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (

        <div className="container">
          <div className="row ">
            {ProductInfo.map((postDetail, index) => {
              return (


                  <div className="col-md-4 ml-auto">

                    <a href="require(`${postDetail.url}`)"><img className="productpic" src={require(`./${postDetail.image}`)} /></a>
                    <h2 className="display-6"> <a href="{postDetail.url}">{postDetail.name}</a></h2>
                    <p className="h4">{postDetail.price}</p>
                    <p className="info">{postDetail.description}</p>
                    <div className="counter">


                        <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.handleIncerement()}>+</button>
                        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
                        <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.handleDecrement()}>-</button>

                    </div>
                  </div>

              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Products
```

and here is my css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

}
#root{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

a .nav-link{
  font-size:4rem;
}

.form-control{
  width:50vh !important;  
}

#logo{
  height:5rem;
}

.nav-item{
  font-size:2rem;
  font-weight:500;
}

.row{
 padding:15vh 0 10vh 0;
}
.row blockquote,p, h2{

  text-align: center;
  font-size:0.9rem;
}
.col-md-4{
  background-color:white;
  max-width:30vh !important;
  display: block;
  margin:0 4vh 7vh 0;  
  padding:5vh 0 5vh 0;
  -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 4px 4px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 4px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         1px 1px 4px 4px #ccc;

}

.info{
  min-height:12vh;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;

}
.productpic{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;

  margin: auto;
  display: block;

}
.display-6 a:link{
    text-decoration: none !important;    
    color:lightgray !important;
}

.display-6 a:hover{
  color:#161616 !important;

  font-weight:650 !important;
}

.container{
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
  background-color:E0E0E0;
}

.blockquote{
  font-size:0.8rem !important;
  max-width:25vh;
  text-align:center;

}
.counter{
  text-align:center;
  display:block;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use a single `count` key to store the data, while your products are in array.
That means, your products basically all refer to the same count.
The best way to handle it is to create a `Product` component, which handles its own counter.

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0, totalPrice: 0 }; 
  }
  handleIncrement = () => {
    const { count, totalPrice } = this.state;
    const { price, increaseTotals } = this.props; 
    const newCount = count + 1;
    const newTotal = newCount * price;
    this.setState({ count: newCount, totalPrice: newTotal }, () => {
      increaseTotals(price);
    });
  }
  handleDecrement = () => {
    const { count, totalPrice } = this.state;
    const { price, decreaseTotals } = this.props; 
    const newCount = count - 1;
    const newTotal = newCount * price;
    this.setState({ count: newCount, totalPrice: newTotal }, () => {
      decreaseTotals(price);
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { url, name, image, price, description } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4 ml-auto">
        <a href="require(`${url}`)"><img className="productpic" src={require(`./${image}`)} /></a>
        <h2 className="display-6"> <a href="{url}">{name}</a></h2>
        <p className="h4">{price}</p>
        <p className="info">{description}</p>
        <div className="counter">
          <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleIncerement}>+</button>
          <div>{this.state.count}</div>
          <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And then implement it in your `Products` component:

```
class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { totalCount: 0, totalPrice: 0 };
  }
  increaseTotals = price => {
    const { totalCount, totalPrice } = this.state;
    const newCount = totalCount + 1;
    const newPrice = newCount * price;
    this.setState({ totalCount: newCount, totalPrice: newPrice }); 
  }
  decreaseTotals = price => {
    const { totalCount, totalPrice } = this.state;
    const newCount = totalCount - 1;
    const newPrice = newCount * price;
    this.setState({ totalCount: newCount, totalPrice: newPrice }); 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row ">
          {ProductInfo.map(postDetail => (
            <Product
              increaseTotals={this.increaseTotals}
              decreaseTotals={this.decreaseTotals}
              {...postDetail}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It will solve your problem by encapsulating needed data in children components and make your code easier to re-implement.

Comment: Great answer thanks now it clear for me. I got a small error Cannot read property ‘setState’ of undefined then I changed Increment and Decrement fucntions and made them arrow function =()=> like this now it works perfect

Comment: @infoperto yeah, I coded this in the answer field, so some little syntax errors could be present, I was mainly trying to illustrate a concept. So sorry.

Comment: I have added my header.js on question as well. Do you know how can I multply each count value with related price and sum all of them in header as TotalCount? If I change this line <div>{this.state.count}</div> into <div className="count">{this.state.count}</div> Is there way to select all value with className "count" and multply the with related price and write in total price with React?

Comment: @infoperto you should keep track of local variables in each Product state, and you can pass updater functions from parent component to keep track of the total. I've updated my post to include that feature.

Comment: @infoperto I've passed my functions from Products, but you can do it from any component or module you want. If it becomes too long of a chain, you can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), if you choose to.